# Nifi Import Large Data Files

Tags: apache-nifi

I am quite new to nifi. We want to download a csv file from an FtpServer and insert in into HDFS.
I have got this working with a small test file by using the getSFTP and putHDFS processors. 
We now want to work with our first actual data file of around 15Gb, and later date files of possibly in the 200-500 GB range. Are there any restrictions pn the size of the files that can be ingested, and if so, how can these be overcome ? 
Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no restrictions on size. However, your NiFi workers' content repositories' should be large enough to contain such files at once.

In any other term, NiFi is designed to move large files.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. Could you please explain some more on "NiFi workers' content repositories' should be large enough to contain such files at once" 
Does it mean that to handle a 15G csv file,  the following value should be set to 15G in nifi.properties :-       nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size 
    and increase it to 500G for a 500G csv file ?

Comment: No, I was just statimg the obvious: The filesystem that would contain the csv would need to at least be able to contain 500gb(but obviously should be larger).

Comment: I wrote a short article about it if you'd like https://link.medium.com/T66On4CJk1